# How can I working a class structure by simply setting up a function structure?

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

How can I write the following class structure without a class and with a function structure?

for example.

```
        function SpecialKeyboard() {
       /* BLA BLA */
        } 
        SpecialKeyboard();
```

The class code:

```
    class SpecialKeyboard extends HTMLElement{
      constructor(){
        super()
        arabic.split('').forEach( char => {
          key.innerHTML = arabic[arabic.indexOf(char)];
          key.onclick = ()=>{
            this.typeInTextarea(TextView,arabic);
            this.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
          }
          center.appendChild(key);
        });
    String.prototype.trToLower = function(){
        var string = this;
        return string.toLowerCase();
    }   
      }
      typeInTextarea(el, newText) {
        var start = el.selectionStart
        var end = el.selectionEnd
        el.value = (before + newText + after)
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = start + newText.length
      } 
    }
    customElements.define('arabic-keyboard',SpecialKeyboard);
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `class` syntax? It seems perfectly appropriate here.

Comment: What is `String.prototype.trToLower = …;` doing in the middle of your constructor?!